# Monad bind insists on different type?

Tags: haskell, monads

why is this not a correct implementation?

```
instance Monad Lock where
   (Working False x) >>= _ = Working False x
   (Working True  x) >>= f = f x
```

The error GHC spits out is the one about rigid type variables:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      (>>=) :: forall a b. Lock a -> (a -> Lock b) -> Lock b
    at src/Computers.hs:32:22
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      (>>=) :: forall a b. Lock a -> (a -> Lock b) -> Lock b
    at src/Computers.hs:32:22
  Expected type: Lock b
    Actual type: Lock a
```

I am probably misinterpreting the error, but from my limited understanding, compiler actually *requires* me to spit out a different parameterized type, rather than the same type.

I tried adding a different constructor without the type parameter (and change semantics just for the test) - then it works fine:

```
instance Monad Lock where
   Broken            >>= _ = Broken
   (Working False x) >>= _ = Broken
   (Working True  x) >>= f = f x
```

Edit:
indeed, the definition of Lock is:

```
data Lock a = Working Bool a
```

Comment: Include the definition of `Lock`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume your definition of `Lock` looks like this:

```
data Lock a = Working Bool a
```

Now, let's look at the type of `(>>=)`:

```
(>>=) :: Lock a -> (a -> Lock b) -> Lock b
```

The important thing here is that it is the caller of `(>>=)` (and not the implementor) that gets to choose the values of `a` and `b`; for example, I might use it as if it had type:

```
(>>=) :: Lock Int -> (Int -> Lock Bool) -> Lock Bool
```

Now it is clear why your implementation is incorrect: in

```
Working False int >>= _ = Working False int
```

you would be returning a `Lock Int` instead of a `Lock Bool`.

Answer (score 2):

The caller has a `Lock a`, and a function `a -> Lock b`, and your implementation of `>>=` must combine those into a `Lock b`. You didn't provide the definition of `Lock`, but I assume it looks like this:

```
data Lock a = Working Bool a
```

The problem in your implementation is that you have an `a`, the second field in the `Working` constructor, and you need a `b` in order to produce a `Lock b`. You can't just return `Working False a`, because that is a `Lock a`, which is not what `>>=` promises to return. The only way you have to get a `b` out of an `a` is through the user's function `f`, so you really have no choice but to call it.

The reason this is not true once you add the `Broken` constructor, is that you can easily construct a `Lock b` now, for any `b`, because `Broken` doesn't require any values of the type it is parameterized over.

You can see the same basic phenomenon with the implementation of

```
(>>=) :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
```

When you write `Nothing >>= f`, there is no `a` to call the function on, so how can a `Maybe b` be constructed? Again, `Nothing` suffices, because it doesn't care what type it is parameterized with.